# Embeddable in ElementCollection gets empty json object

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-restcontroller

I have an entity where one of its properties is a list of `AnnotationTarget` which is defined as an `@Embeddable`

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = AnnotationTarget.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "annotation_targets", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "annotation_id"))
private List<AnnotationTarget> targets = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my RestController I've made a POST to create my entity and I see that the entity gets created and the `@Embeddable` is created as well in the `annotation_targets` table properly.  When I make a GET request to this same resource it returns all the elements of the entity but the targets I get an array of 1 element which is an empty JSON.

```
{
"id": "9c3e56b6-97ea-40fb-aa06-991826b34751",
"userId": "883233d5-b00f-464a-9f26-f7e2dd0a6a7b",
"type": "TEXT",
"targets": [
    {}
],
"createdAt": 1520626966343,
"updatedAt": 1520626966343
}
```

Printing some statements I do see that `getTargets()` returns data so not sure why this would be empty?  Any help would be great

Comment: Just a wild guess, but does `@ElementCollection(fetch=EAGER,...)` help? If not, please post the `AnnotationTarget` class

Comment: @criz - I figured it out for my case as I'm using lombok, I didn't have the `@Data` annotation on my AnnotationTarget class so that was what was causing the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!